# How to read a file with '.sww' format?

Tags: python-2.7, file, format, output, software-distribution

I am working with open source package written in python.
Its output is a file with .sww format.
I am unable to find a software which can read this.
Please kindly reply if you know.

Thank you
[this is picture of the file icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6T7b.png)

Comment: What open source package is this? What kind of data is supposed to be in this file?

Comment: Open source package name is ANUGA hydrodynamic modeling package

Answer (score 0):

It's time to answer my own question.

SWW file format is a NetCDF format for storing model output with mesh information f(t,x,y).

One such use of SWW file extension is 
In **ANUGA, a hydrodynamic modelling**. It's used for storing the model output and therefore pertains to a set of points and a set of times at which a model is evaluated. 
The contents of an SWW file may be viewed using the anuga viewer anuga_viewer, which creates an on-screen visualisation.